# Trying to Change my ViewController to full screen but can't

Tags: xcode, fullscreen, viewcontroller

I know there are many questions and answers about how to make a ViewController full screen. My problem is little odd. I am not using Navigation Bar and when I try to set my modalPresentationStyle to fullScreen my View is showing and than hiding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably due to code you have not shown us, such as a bad `viewWillDisappear` in the previous (select place to ride) view controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, definately viewWillDisappear was causing the problem.

Comment: Might be useful to others so I'll repeat it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to code you have not shown us, such as a bad `viewWillDisappear` in the previous (*select place to ride*) view controller.

You didn't experience the issue before because a presented view controller that isn't full screen doesn't cause the previous view controller to disappear.